# Printing object keys and values in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object and need to print out the object keys and values without using loops or if-else statements. I am allowed to use template literals. (I'm new to JavaScript programming)

let TLOP = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "West",
    age: "28",
    hairColor: "black" 
};

Comment: `without ... statements` - right - good luck .. so ... `\`${TLOP.firstName}\`` etc?

Comment: use `alert(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, null, 4));`

Comment: if the object has arbitrary keys that you do not know beforehand ... how will you access them all without some sort of loop ... or statement for that matter?

Comment: you'll still need to show what your expected output is ... "print out" means nothing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is considered "statements" by your terms, but this is the only way I can think of without using loops:

```js
let TLOP = { firstName: "John", lastName: "West", age: "28", hairColor: "black" };

console.log(Object.keys(TLOP))
console.log(Object.values(TLOP))
```

Comment: but that doesn't use "template literals" :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let TLOP = { firstName: "John", lastName: "West", age: "28", hairColor: "black" }

let TLOP_keys = Object.keys(TLOP);
let TLOP_entries = Object.values(TLOP);

console.log(TLOP_keys);
console.log(TLOP_entries);
```

Comment: but that doesn't use "template literals" :D

Comment: And what's that supposed to be?

Comment: it's in the question ... "I am allowed to use template literals"

Comment: He CAN use whatever they are, but it's not required.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your answer :p - you could also just `console.log(Object.entries(TLOP))` and that "prints" keys and values in one ... erm .. statement :p